# Extrair arquivo do banco (varbinary) e usa-lo na web

Tags: javascript, sql-server, varbinary

Tenho arquivos salvos em uma coluna do meu banco (**SQLSERVER**) do tipo **varbinary** e preciso **recuperar** esses arquivos salvos nessa coluna e ***mostrá***-**los** em uma modal ou **baixá**-**los**; porém, preciso fazer isso usando **JS**. Alguém consegue ajudar-me?

Comment: Não grave arquivos, especialmente se forem grandes, no DB (isso destrói a performance) a menos que vc esteja usando as funcionalidades de File Stream.